# Laravel 5.1.11 migrate with php artisan does not work for me

Tags: laravel-5.1, database-migration

I am using *Laravel 5.1.11* but when I try to run `php artisan migrate` command I am faced with the following error message:

```
 ****[symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] syntax Error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)****
```

With database connection configuration in `database.php` and `.env` is quite fine because `php artisan migrate:install` works just fine.

this is the migration code:

```
   **<?php
        use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
        use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
        class CreateFlightsTables extends Migration
        {
            /**
             * Run the migrations.
             *
                //
                Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {

             * @return void
             */
           public function up()
        {
            //
            Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('airline');
                $table->timestamps();
        }
            /**
             * Reverse the migrations.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function down()
            {
                //
                Schema::drop('flights');
            }
        }**
```

Comment: Can you post some of the source of the migration and code used in the migration that is yours? That error looks like there's a syntax error in one of your files and it may not be the migration.

Comment: paste your migration code here, so we can find error.

Comment: Note the migration file below:

Comment: Please mark question as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your `function up()` with

```
Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('airline');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Think you are missing bracket and semicolon at the end